# Error with using side-by-side, nudged graphs in ggplot (facet_wrap and position_nudge)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create side-by-side plots with nudged data points (Odds ratios, with 95% CI error bars) in R using ggplot. Each time I try to combine them I get an error. Can anyone help me identify what I should do to change my code? This is the error I get:

> Error in (~surv) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 4, 1)) : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

To illustrate what I'm trying to do, see below a version I created using plot(), which you can see is fairly ugly: [image: Example of plot I want to create using ggplot] I've tried combining the facet_wrap and position_nudge based on the guidance in the J Stuart Carlton blog, but haven't been able to add a position_nudge. The error code above suggests that the problem is with facet_wrap section of my code. [image]

I've included code below describing how to replicate my dataset.

```
activity <- factor(rep(c("Good interaction", "Poor interaction",
                              "RTW plan"), times = 4))
surv <- factor(rep(c("T1", "T2"), each = 3, times = 2))
mod <- factor(rep(c("Crude", "Adjusted"), each = 6))
or <- c(1.72, 1.26, 2.39, 2.5, 1.34, 1.89, 1.14, 1.09, 2.02, 1.9, 1.1, 1.02)
low <- c(1.22, 0.74, 1.73, 1.74, 0.61, 1.35, 0.77, 0.61, 1.40, 1.22, 0.60, 0.68)
hi <- c(2.41, 2.16, 3.29, 3.6, 1.8, 2.64, 1.70, 1.94, 2.90, 2.95, 2.04, 1.54)
rtwc <- data.frame(activity, surv, mod, or, low, hi)
```

And here is the ggplot code I've been using:

```
ggplot(rtwc, aes(x = or, y = activity, colour = mod)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = 0.25, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_errorbarh(data = filter(rtwc, mod == "crude"), aes(xmax = hi, xmin = low), size = 0.5, height = 0.1, colour = "gray50", position = position_nudge(y = fix)) + 
  geom_point(data = filter(rtwc, mod == "crude"), aes(xmax = hi, xmin = low), size = 4, position_nudge(y = fix)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(data = filter(rtwc, mod == "Adjusted"), aes(xmax = hi, xmin = low), size = 0.5, height = 0.1, colour = "gray50", position = position_nudge(y = -fix)) + 
  geom_point(data = filter(rtwc, mod == "Adjusted"), size = 4, position = position_nudge(y = -fix)) +   
  geom_errorbarh(data = filter(rtwc, mod = "Adjusted")) + 
  facet_wrap = (~surv) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 4, 1)) + 
  coord_trans(x = "log10") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Apologies if there is already a post on this question.

Comment: I don't think the first one is ugly at all.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. My concern is that there is a lot of empty space that the ggplot version makes much better use of. I've presented the plot() version before with no issue, but think it would be valuable to update for future presentations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some code to get you started. I used `position_dodge` together with `coord_flip` to keep the error bar pairs away from each other:

```
ggplot(rtwc,
       aes(y = or, ymin = low, ymax = hi, x = activity, group = mod)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, size = 0.25, linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey") +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = mod), position = position_dodge(0.5),
             size = 3) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "") +
  scale_y_log10(name = "", breaks = seq(0, 4)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("red", "blue")) + # change colours here
  expand_limits(y = c(0.1, 4)) + #adjust x axis range here
  facet_wrap(~surv) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw() + #change look & feel here
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image: coefficient plot]

For tweaks to the plot's look & feel, you can check out the available themes in `ggplot` [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html), & more themes in `ggthemes` [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggthemes/vignettes/ggthemes.html). Just please don't use the Excel 2013 theme. As the creator noted, its presence is for ironic purposes only.

For tweaks to the point colours, here's a [handy reference](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour) for colours by name. Or you can use one of the palettes from `RColorBrewer`, viewable via `RColorBrewer::display.brewer.all()`.

Comment: Thank you, Z. This is just what I was looking for. Really helpful of you to add the notes to the code as well!

Comment: As a side note: you can use `geom_errorbarh` instead of `geom_errorbar` so you don't need `coord_flip`.